# Trying to add Color Hover Transition on SVG, but Color goes Yellow between Orange to White... Instead of just Orange to White

Tags: html, css

Trying to add color hover transition on SVG, but Color goes Yellow between Orange to White... Instead of just Orange to White.

```html
<div id="page-hero-svgs">
                    <img src="./images/github-svg.svg" alt="" id="github" class="svg-icon">
                    <img src="./images/linkedin-svg.svg" alt="" id="linkedin" class="svg-icon">
                    <img src="./images/email-svg.svg" alt="" id="email" class="svg-icon">
                </div>
```

```css
.svg-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    filter: invert(62%) sepia(100%) saturate(7380%) hue-rotate(26deg) brightness(95%) contrast(90%);
    fill: rgb(255, 98, 0);
}

.svg-icon:hover {
    filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(10000%) hue-rotate(0deg) brightness(100%) contrast(100%);
    fill: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: ease-in 0.3s;
}
```

Is there anyway where it just goes smoothly from orange to white?

Thank in advance,

Jake

Expected smooth transition to white, but I think the filter props are causing grief.

How can I implement inline SVGS that are the same size as the ones currently so I can manipulate the css easily?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is likely due to the filter property in your CSS. It's also transitioning, which is why you're seeing a yellow color during the transition from orange to white.

A potential solution is to use inline SVGs and directly change the fill property. Here's how you can do it:

```
<div id="page-hero-svgs">
    <svg id="github" class="svg-icon">
        <use xlink:href="./images/github-svg.svg"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg id="linkedin" class="svg-icon">
        <use xlink:href="./images/linkedin-svg.svg"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg id="email" class="svg-icon">
        <use xlink:href="./images/email-svg.svg"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.svg-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    fill: rgb(255, 98, 0);
    transition: fill 0.3s ease-in;
}

.svg-icon:hover {
    fill: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Please ensure that your SVG files are configured to allow the fill property to be changed. This typically means that the fill attribute in the SVG file itself should be set to currentColor.